# What is different about Unity's AnimationCurve serialization/assignment and why does my example fails?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

**SUMMARY**

I ran into a unexpected problem when trying the following operations using Unity's [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html):

```
x = A (via serialization/deserialization)
y = x
x = B (via serialization/deserialization)

Assert that y equals A
```

As illustrated by the pseudocode, I expect y to be equal to A. However that does not seem to be working for the `AnimationCurve` type. Why is this the case?

---

**FULL EXPLANATION**

To exemplify what is happening, I have setup a test case for this using NUnit. The test, as implemented below, DOES NOT PASS.

```cs
public class AnimationCurveMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimationCurve myCurve;
}
```

```cs
[Test]
public void SetValueViaSerialization_SetsAThenB_HasValueAInTheMiddle()
{
    // INITIALIZATION
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject();
    AnimationCurveMonoBehaviour animationCurveMonoBehaviour = gameObject.AddComponent<AnimationCurveMonoBehaviour>();

    AnimationCurve animationCurveA = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 1));
    AnimationCurve animationCurveB = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 2));

    // EXECUTION
    this.SetAnimationCurveValue(animationCurveMonoBehaviour, animationCurveA);
    AnimationCurve sample = animationCurveMonoBehaviour.myCurve;
    this.SetAnimationCurveValue(animationCurveMonoBehaviour, animationCurveB);

    // ASSERTION
    Assert.AreEqual(animationCurveA, sample); // FAILS
}

private void SetAnimationCurveValue(AnimationCurveMonoBehaviour animationCurveMonoBehaviour, AnimationCurve animationCurve)
{
    SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(animationCurveMonoBehaviour);
    SerializedProperty sut = serializedObject.FindProperty("myCurve");
    sut.animationCurveValue = animationCurve;
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

By running the same test (with the appropriate type modifications) with all of the types listed below, the tests PASSES.

```
int
bool
float
string
Color
Vector2
Vector3
Vector4
Rect
Bounds
Quaternion
Vector2Int
Vector3Int
RectInt
BoundsInt
GameObject
TMP_FontAsset
Sprite
```

But what is really weird is that the following similar tests also work as intended when using `AnimationCurve`:

```cs
//...
// EXECUTION
this.SetAnimationCurveValue(animationCurveMonoBehaviour, animationCurveA);
AnimationCurve sample = animationCurveMonoBehaviour.myCurve;
Assert.AreEqual(animationCurveA, sample); // PASSES
//...
```

```cs
//...
// EXECUTION
this.SetAnimationCurveValue(animationCurveMonoBehaviour, animationCurveA);
this.SetAnimationCurveValue(animationCurveMonoBehaviour, animationCurveB);
AnimationCurve sample = animationCurveMonoBehaviour.myCurve;
Assert.AreEqual(animationCurveB, sample); // PASSES
//...
```

What is different about `AnimationCurve` and what is happening in my example?

Comment: Hard to say what's happening here.  From the [reference source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Animation/AnimationCurve.bindings.cs#L314) it looks like the unmanaged method `AnimationCurveBindings::Internal_Equals` is called on the unmanaged `IntPtr m_Ptr` members.  Possibly that unmanaged method checks equality of some `float` values that lose a little precision during serialization?  Or perhaps it uses pointer equality for some embedded member?

Comment: There's clearly an attempt to implement value equality instead of reference equality so you might file an issue with unity.  (That being said, their [implementation of `GetHashCode()`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Animation/AnimationCurve.bindings.cs#L319) seems to imply that equality devolves to reference equality of `m_Ptr` so maybe they really aren't trying to implement value equality...)

Comment: I have just submitted a bug report with Unity. I will maintain this thread updated if I receive any answer.

Comment: Can you share a link to the report?

Comment: The email I received with the status URL states "Note that sharing it will also share all your other cases and email conversations in them.". Because of that, I believe I should not share the link to the report. But rest assured that I recreated the test case and submitted to them, with a similar explanation to the one in this question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was thinking it might show up here https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/product/unity/issues?view=newest

Comment: I believe it only ends up there after they have successfully reproduced the issue.

Comment: I received a response. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055555/8041632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the QA support was:

> Generally, You should keep `AreEqual` for basic types (such as "int", "bool", "string" etc.).
>   It generally won't work well for anything that contains objects or that are objects.
>   Although Object is a class it is not intended to be used widely in script.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.AreEqual.html contains a lot of useful information on this matter, and it mentions the usage of System.Object objects, not UnityEngine.Object objects (and Animation Curve is exactly that).

Comment: If anyone could elaborate on top of the answer, I would be grateful. In some sense, "i disagree" that this is working as intended. But for now, I consider this question "closed" and I will try a workaround.